# how to remove startDestination when creating deepLink with NavDeepLinkBuilder?

Tags: android, android-notifications, deep-linking, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

imagine I have navGraph like this with startDestination="@id/rootFragment" :

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/rootFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rootFragment"
        android:name="com.nima.RootFragment"
        android:label="rootFragment">
    //some actions...
    </fragment>

    //other fragments...
</navigation>
```

and I want to create a Deeplink like this:

```
NavDeepLinkBuilder(context).
      addDestination(R.id.FragmentA).
      addDestination(R.id.FragmentB).
      setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph).
      createPendingIntent()
```

so I want to show FragmentA first and FragmentB next, and when the user hits the back button only show the FragmentA and not showing the startDestination(rootFragment).
by default, the startDestination is in backStack, my question is how can I remove it?

NavDeepLinkBuilder has no method like PopUpto to remove it.

Comment: As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), your start destination should always be the last thing the user sees before they go back to the launcher. Is your "RootFragment" one of the cases like login that are specifically called out as never appropriate to be the start destination your graph?

Comment: yes, for some scenarios I have to remove it from backStack.

Comment: That's never the correct thing to do. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where your problem is caused by your attempted solution to some other problem (the existence / role of `RootFragment`) that you actually need to solve correctly to avoid this question in the first place. Maybe you can explain how you got into this situation from the beginning?

Comment: from (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), I don't have a fixed destination, and my rootFragment decides to go to which fragment.

Comment: That is exactly what you should **not** be doing, as explained on that page and on the [conditional navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional). Maybe you should be asking a different question about how to remove your `RootFragment` and do that correctly and link that question here?